# Insert data for two tables using single form in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

good day for all. I have 2 tables in database, first table is Travel table contains id, subject, purpose, amount. Second table is Accomodation contains id, travelplan, location, travel_id. So far i have tried to insert data for Travel and Accomodation table within Travel form but always failed.

Travel form

```
$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
$acc_travelplan = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('acc_travelplan');
$acc_location = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('acc_location');
$subject = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('subject');
$purpose = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('purpose');
$amount = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('amount');

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');
$submit->setAttrib('class', 'btn btn-primary');
$submit->setLabel('Save As Draft');

$this->addElements(array(
            $id, $acc_travelplan, $acc_location, $subject, $purpose, $amount, $submit
        ));
$this->setElementDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
```

Travel Controller (Add Action)

```
$msgarray = array();

$travelmodel = new Default_Model_Travel();
$travelform = new Default_Form_Travel();
$travelform->setAttrib('action',BASE_URL.'travel/add');

/*
Create Accomodation
*/
if($this->_request->getParam('travelplan'))
        {
            $travelform->setDefault('acc_travelplan', $this->_request->getParam('travelplan'));
        }

        if($this->_request->getParam('location'))
        {
            $travelform->setDefault('acc_location', $this->_request->getParam('location'));
        }

$this->view->form = $travelform;

if($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
            $result = $this->save($travelform);  
            $this->view->form = $travelform;          
            $this->view->msgarray = $result; 
        }
```

Travel Controller (Save Action)

```
public function save($travelform)
    {   
        $result ="";

        if($travelform->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
        {

            $trDb = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();     

            $trDb->beginTransaction();
            try
            {
                $travelmodel = new Default_Model_Travel();

                $id = $this->_request->getParam('id'); 
                $subject = $this->_request->getParam('subject');
                $purpose = $this->_request->getParam('purpose');
                $amount = $this->_request->getParam('amount');
                $data = array(  
                                'subject'=>$subject,
                                'purpose'=>$purpose,
                                'amount'=>$amount,
                            );

                $Id = $travelmodel->SaveOrUpdateTravelData($data);

                if($id)
                {
                    $tableid = $id;
                    $this->_helper->getHelper("FlashMessenger")->addMessage(array("success"=>"travel updated successfully."));
                }   
                else
                {

                    if(!empty($this->_request->getParam('acc_travelplan')))
                    {
                        $this->saveTake($accomodationId);       
                    }     

                    $tableid = $Id;     
                    $this->_helper->getHelper("FlashMessenger")->addMessage(array("success"=>"travel added successfully."));                                       
                } 

                $trDb->commit();

                $this->_redirect('travel/index');                  
            }
            catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                $trDb->rollBack();
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            $messages = $travelform->getMessages();

            foreach ($messages as $key => $val)
            {
                foreach($val as $key2 => $val2)
                {
                    $msgarray[$key] = $val2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $msgarray;   
        }
    }

public function saveTake($accomodationId)
    {   
        $accomodationform = new Default_Form_Accomodation();        

        $result ="";

        if($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
            try
            {
                $accomodationmodel = new Default_Model_Accomodation();    
                $id='';
                $travelplan = $this->_request->getParam('acc_travelplan');
                $location = $this->_request->getParam('acc_location');

                $data = array(
                                'travelplan'=>$travelplan,
                                'location'=>$location,
                            );

                $Id = $accomodationmodel->SaveOrUpdateAccomodation($data);

                if($id)
                {
                    $tableid = $id;
                    $this->_helper->getHelper("FlashMessenger")->addMessage(array("success"=>"Accomodation updated successfully."));
                }   
                else
                {
                    $tableid = $Id;     
                    $this->_helper->getHelper("FlashMessenger")->addMessage(array("success"=>"Accomodation added successfully."));                       
                }   

            }
            catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                $trDb->rollBack();
                $msgarray= "Something went wrong, please try again later.";
            }
        }
    }
```

After i saved a travel form, the datas cannot inserted to the Accomodation table but only inserted to the Travel table. Anybody's can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place  your saveTake function call inside if case not inside else case.  I mean after your flash messager success message "travel updated successfully"

You can use `$tablemodel->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();` to get inserted travel_id in travel table and pass that for Accomodation table data array. first print $id after saveorupdate travel data if it is the inserted id then you do not need to use lastInsertId() just pass that to saveTake function.

Comment: try printing exception message.I think you are missing travel_id for Accomodation table. If it is a foreign key you have to pass value for that. use inserted id from travel table and pass that id for Accomodation table.